# Apache VFS2 reply timeout from the server

Tags: java, vfs, apache-commons-vfs, vfs-stream

I am using VFS2 to upload file to remote hosts (FTP, SFTP) for my clients but sometimes i have to wait up to 5 minutes to get a timeout if connection is established but the server doesn't reply. 
E.g. apache vfs receives a connection from remote host on port 22 but on the remote host port 22 is used by ssh server not by SFTP server and that's why vfs waits 5 minutes for a reply before closing a connection (different protocols are used that's why the server cannot reply to a client). My question is how to configure VFS do not wait for a such long time and configure timeout for that case ?

Comment: What have you tried to set the timeout?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `setSessionTimeoutMillis`

See this [link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs//commons-vfs2/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/vfs2/provider/sftp/SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.html#line.464)

Comment: Hey. My config includes setConnectTimeout(this, 30000) for Ftp and Sftp .
setSessionTimeoutMillis(this, 30000) is used for Sftp and for FTP i will try to use setDataTimeout(this, 30000)